# How do I pass a context to an AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to preform a `Toast` when a background task is completed, just to let the user know that it's finished.

I've made a new class for my asyncTask, but I cannot use `getApplicationContext()` within this class.

I'm using `task.execute(getTempFile(this), getApplicationContext());` to run the tasks. getTempFile returns a File object, and I was trying to pass the context as a Context object.

My Task class has three variables, `AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Integer>`, so the context is in the second object. However, this crashes the application.

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    protected void handleImage(Bitmap thumbnail) {
        PushDataToServer task = new PushDataToServer();
        task.execute(getTempFile(this), getApplicationContext());
    }
}


public class PushDataToServer extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Integer> {

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.context = (Context) params[1];
        File file = (File) params[0];
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.context, "All done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Pass a `Context` object into the `AsyncTask`'s constructor.

Sample code:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<?, ? ,?> {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    } 
}
```

and then, when you are constructing your `AsyncTask`:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(this);
task.execute(...);
```

Comment: The `Toast` should be shown when you are calling `show()` on it in functions that runs on  the UI thread. Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: The toast is in my onPostExecute() method. The code sample is above.

Comment: I can perfectly show `Toast`s in my `onPostExecute()` method. I suspect that you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: By the way, change your argument in the `onPostExecute()` method from `String` to `Integer` since it is the type of object your `onPostExecute()` expects. For all your current class know, the `onPostExecute()` method is just like an ordinary method which currently has nothing related with your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: In your onPostExecute, call a static method defined in your activity.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: No, there is definitely no need for that. That's just a dirty solution.

Comment: can't this cause a leak if the activity is destroyed before the asynctask is finished?

Comment: The IDE says "Issue id: StaticFieldLeak"

Answer (score 2):

Pass it in the constructor, not as a method parameter. Then you don't need to depend on the generic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Complete example: [Reusable AsyncTask](https://github.com/levinotik/ReusableAsyncTask)

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Does not address the problem of passing a context into the background task.

Answer (score 0):

You say your context is in the second object, yet your second object is Integer. Could this be your problem? Also - another suggestion is to put your AsyncTask class as a private inner class to your activity - that way I am pretty sure you will have access to getApplicationContext().