# Proper way to terminate Async Task and inform the user:

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am inserting a record into a DB which has a unique constriant on two fields - Name and DOB. I insert from the DoInBackground() method of the Async task. I do it as follows:

```
try{
                        insertInDb(name.trim(),start_date.trim(),imagePath.trim(), String.valueOf(TYPE),String.valueOf(SELECTION), name_friend.trim(), isAdhoc);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println("Caught up here"+e);
                        return "Record Exists";
                    }
```

Here is my postExecute():

```
public void onPostExecute(String result){
            //TODO
            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Record Exists")){
                if(Asycdialog !=null && Asycdialog.isShowing())
                    Asycdialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Exists please try a different name and year", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            }else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("Success")){
                if(Asycdialog !=null && Asycdialog.isShowing()){
                    Asycdialog.dismiss();

                    Intent mainIntent;
                    mainIntent = new Intent(AdhocCase.this,MainActivity.class); 
                    AdhocCase.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    AdhocCase.this.finish(); 
                }
            }
```

The toast message in case of "Record Exists" when returned from doInBackground never seems to execute. However the intent does change.

Here is my complete doInBackground():

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try{
        System.out.println("Type in async: "+type);
        System.out.println("Selection in async: "+String.valueOf(SELECTION));
        System.out.println("TYPE in async: "+String.valueOf(TYPE));
        dbHelper.open(); 

        Cursor checkCur = dbHelper.checkIfRecordExists(name.trim(), start_date.trim()); 
        System.out.println("Cursor count"+checkCur.getCount()); 
        if(checkCur != null && checkCur.moveToFirst()){
            System.out.println("Exists"); 
            return "Record Exists";
        }else{
            System.out.println("Image path: "+imagePath);
            insertAdhocCase(toTitleCase(name).trim(),start_date.trim(),imagePath, type, String.valueOf(SELECTION), toTitleCase(name_friend).trim());

            try{
                insertInDb(name.trim(),start_date.trim(),imagePath.trim(), String.valueOf(TYPE),String.valueOf(SELECTION), name_friend.trim(), isAdhoc);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Caught up here"+e);
                return "Record Exists";
            }   
        //  LC.writeToSDCard();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        //  System.out.println(e); 
    }

    return "Success";
}
```

}

Comment: do you mean `return "Record Exists";` is not working?

Comment: You can't `Toast` message in `doInBackground()`

Comment: I am toasting in onPostExecute matey.

Comment: @BlazeTama yes - exactly!

Comment: How about using AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED?

Comment: I change the intent inside of the onPostExecute, I will chck if that is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record Exists please try a different name and year", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You must explicitly provide the context from the calling Activity something like

```
Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Record Exists please try a different name and year", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066264/how-do-i-pass-a-context-to-an-asynctask?answertab=oldest#tab-top) for reference.